# Date program and incrementing each day

Tags: java, date

I am completely lost on this problem. We are to create a program that allows a user to input a date (month, day, year), and the program should print out that date and increment by 1 each day after. if the date enter fell on the last day of the month. The month needs to be incremented by one, and the next day should start back on 1. If the December 31, xxx1 is entered. then the month, day, and year should change to January 1, xxx2. Also, if the date falls on a leap year. Say like it the input is Feb. 15, 2009. The dates should increment up to Feb 29 if not a leap year it should print out Feb 28.

I'm completely stumped on how to solve this problem. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Here what I have:

```
package date;

public class Date 
{
  private static final int February = 2;
  private static final int December = 12;
  private int month;
  private int day;
  private int year;

  public Date()
  {
    month = 1;
    day = 1;
    year = 2000;
  }

  public Date(int month, int day, int year)
  {
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;       
  }

  public void setMonth(int month)
  {
    this.month = month;
  }

  public void setDay(int day)
  {
    this.day = day;
  }

  public void setYear(int year)
  {
    this.year = year;
  }

  public int getMonth(int month)
  {
    return month;
  }

  public int getDay(int day)
  {
    return day;
  }

  public static int getYear(int year)
  {
    return year;
  }

  public boolean nextDay()
  { 
    boolean leapYear = false;
    int currentMonthMaxDays;
    int [] daysInMonths = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    currentMonthMaxDays = daysInMonths[month];
    if(day < currentMonthMaxDays)
    {
        day = day + 1;
        day++;
    }

    else if(month == February && leapYear && day == 28)
    {
        day = 29;
        day++;
    }
        else day = 1;

            if(month != December)

                month +=1;

                else 
                    year+=1;
                    month = 1;

    while(!leapYear)
    {
        if(year % 400 ==0)
            leapYear = true;
        else if(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)
            leapYear = true;

    }
        return leapYear;
  } 

}
```

I think I did the Date.java class properly my problem lies in the main class. we have to create an array that increments the date by 1. I'm trying to see up to 30-31 days a month.

Here's the DateTest main:

```
 package date;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;


 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 public class DateTest {


 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    Date [] date = new Date[2];

    for(int i = 1; i < date.length; i++)
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Date (e.g. 19991231): ");
        date[i] = new Date();
        i++;
    }
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Date: " + date, "Results", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
 }
}
```

I know for sure my main is pretty jacked up. and I'm really lost on the assignment.

Comment: why not use `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: @JigarJoshi Well, based on the way the question is worded ("WE have to do this"), this is probably for a class, and figuring out the mathematic logic behind this is part of the homework assignment.

Comment: I think the problem is with your test class...

Comment: It would probably be simpler to store the date in your class as the number of days past January 1, 1970.  You'd have to convert a date to an integer, and convert an integer to a date, but the day increment would be simple.

Comment: Your question is not very clear -- do you want to print the next day or all following days until the next month rolls, or what? Why does your `nextDay` function return a boolean?

Comment: Your `for-loop` in `nextDay` is broken...it's an infinite loop...

Comment: I'm trying to print the day that was inputed and the following days after

Comment: for loop in nextDay?

Comment: Up to what? It shouldn't be infinity...

Comment: Could anyone please give an example of how to use an array of dates? I probably could figure out the rest. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I commented that storing the date internally as the number of days past a base date would be easier to code.

Here's one version of a Date class that stores the date internally as the number of days past a base date:

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.security.InvalidParameterException;

public class Date {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    private static final int BASE_MONTH = 1;
    private static final int BASE_YEAR = 1700;

    private int days; 

    public Date(int month, int day, int year) {
        setDate(month, day, year);
    }

    public void setDate(int month, int day, int year) {
        if ((month >= 1) && (month <= 12)) {            
        } else {
            String s = "Month not between 1 and 12";
            throw new InvalidParameterException(s); 
        }

        if (year >= BASE_YEAR) {
            int temp = calculateMonthDays(month, year);
            if ((day >= 1) && (day <= temp)) {              
            } else {
                String s = "Day not between 1 and " + temp;
                throw new InvalidParameterException(s); 
            }

            int days = calculateYearDays(year); 
            if (DEBUG)  {
                System.out.println(days);
                System.out.println(temp);
            }

            days += temp;
            this.days = days + day;
            if (DEBUG) {
                System.out.println(day);
                System.out.println(this.days);
            }
        } else {
            String s = "Year before " + BASE_YEAR;
            throw new InvalidParameterException(s); 
        }
    }

    public int[] getDate() {
        int days = this.days;
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println(days);

        int year = BASE_YEAR; 
        int decrement = daysInYear(year);
        while (days > decrement) {
            days -= decrement;
            decrement = daysInYear(++year);
        }
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println(days);

        int month = BASE_MONTH;
        decrement = daysInMonth(month, year);
        while (days > decrement) {
            days -= decrement;
            decrement = daysInMonth(++month, year);
        }
        if (DEBUG) System.out.println(days);

        int day = days;

        int[] result = new int[3];
        result[0] = month;
        result[1] = day;
        result[2] = year;

        return result;
    }

    public String getFormattedDate() {
        String[] months = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
        int[] fields = getDate();
        return String.format("%s %d, %d", months[fields[0] - 1], 
                fields[1], fields[2]); 
    }

    public void addDays(int increment) {
        this.days += increment;
    }

    private int calculateMonthDays(int month, int year) {
        int days = 0;

        for (int i = BASE_MONTH; i < month; i++) {
            days += daysInMonth(i, year);
        }

        return days;
    }

    private int calculateYearDays(int year) {
        int days = 0;

        for (int i = BASE_YEAR; i < year; i++) {
            days += daysInYear(i);
        }

        return days;
    }

    private int daysInMonth(int month, int year) {
        int[] days = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

        if (month == 2) {
            if (daysInYear(year) > 365) {
                return days[month - 1] + 1;
            } 
        }

        return days[month - 1];
    }

    private int daysInYear(int year) {
        int days = 365;

        if ((year % 4) == 0) {
            if ((year % 100) == 0) {
                if ((year % 400) == 0) {
                    days++;
                }
            } else {
                days++;
            }
        }

        return days;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date(6, 12, 2014);
        displayResult(date, 10);

        date = new Date(6, 12, 2014);
        displayResult(date, 20);

        date = new Date(12, 15, 2014);
        displayResult(date, 20);

        date = new Date(12, 15, 1955);
        displayResult(date, 30);

        date = new Date(12, 15, 1955);
        displayResult(date, -30);

        date = new Date(12, 15, 1955);
        displayResult(date, 16);

        date = new Date(12, 15, 1955);
        displayResult(date, 17);

        date = new Date(12, 15, 1955);
        displayResult(date, 80);

        date = new Date(12, 15, 1956);
        displayResult(date, 80);

        date = new Date(3, 5, 1957);
        displayResult(date, -80);

        date = new Date(3, 5, 1956);
        displayResult(date, -80);
    }

    private static void displayResult(Date date, int increment) {
        String sign = "";
        int display = 0;

        if (increment > 0) {
            sign = " + ";
            display = increment;
        } else {
            sign = " - ";
            display = -increment;
        }

        System.out.print(date.getFormattedDate() + sign +
                display + " days -> ");
        date.addDays(increment);
        System.out.println(date.getFormattedDate());
    }

}
```

And here are some test results.

```
Jun 12, 2014 + 10 days -> Jun 22, 2014
Jun 12, 2014 + 20 days -> Jul 2, 2014
Dec 15, 2014 + 20 days -> Jan 4, 2015
Dec 15, 1955 + 30 days -> Jan 14, 1956
Dec 15, 1955 - 30 days -> Nov 15, 1955
Dec 15, 1955 + 16 days -> Dec 31, 1955
Dec 15, 1955 + 17 days -> Jan 1, 1956
Dec 15, 1955 + 80 days -> Mar 4, 1956
Dec 15, 1956 + 80 days -> Mar 5, 1957
Mar 5, 1957 - 80 days -> Dec 15, 1956
Mar 5, 1956 - 80 days -> Dec 16, 1955
```

Using the same private methods for converting the date to an integer, and converting the integer to a date helped some.  The DEBUG displays helped me fix my other errors.